# how to use a NSDecimalNumber object value in a different function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to objective and I wanted to know how to do this.

I have a function where I do some calculation and store the result in a NSDecimalNumber object.
I want to use that result in a different function.can anyone help me! thanks!

Example:

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    NSDecimalNumber *one = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"1"];
    NSDecimalNumber *two = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"2"];
    //result is a NSDecimalNumber object created in my .h file 
    result = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]init];
    result = [one decimalNumberByAdding:two];
    //result is now equal to 3 

}
- (IBAction)findResult:(id)sender{
    NSDecimalNumber *findNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]init];
    //I want "findNumber" to have the same value as result, which was given the value of 3 in method calculate  
    findNumber = result; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the variable like that, you don't need to call alloc/init first.  EG, your first method can just be

```
NSDecimalNumber *one = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"1"];
NSDecimalNumber *two = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"2"];    
result = [one decimalNumberByAdding:two];
```

Assuming, that is, that you've declared result before as in:

```
@interface MyClass {
NSDecimalNumber *result;
}
```

Then, in your second function, if you really need a copy of result instead of just referring to the result variable itself, you could do:

```
NSDecimalNumber *findNumber = [result copy];
```

Remember to release when you're done.